# HTML5 audiopayer Whow paused all element audio?

Tags: html, audio, html5-audio

Tell me please when stop all element audio with class 'media_audio_player'
    
    `example:`

```
<audio src="./ConcertMedia/'.$i2['file'].'" class="media_audio_player"> </audio>
<audio src="./ConcertMedia/'.$i2['file'].'" class="media_audio_player"> </audio>
<audio src="./ConcertMedia/'.$i2['file'].'" class="media_audio_player"> </audio>
i want use code $('.media_audio_player').get(0).pause(); but he doesnt work...
Why not work code and what me need doing?
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check the code which plays the sound based on class applied to audio Tags.

```
    <html>
    <head>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function playerClicked() {
        audio=$(".audioplayer").get(1);

            debugger;
            audio.load()
            if(audio.paused){
                audio.play();
            } else {
                audio.pause();
            }

    }
    </script>

    </head>
    <body>

    <a id ="storyplayer" href="javascript:playerClicked();">
    Click here to play.
    </a>
    <audio class ="audioplayer">
        <source src="sound/siol.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" >
    </audio>
    <audio class ="audioplayer">
        <source src="sound/siol.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" >
    </audio>
    </body>
    </html>
```